# Resolved: Sanity.io Deploy fails even though local host says query exists

Tags: deployment, graphql, sanity

I have been building a website with Sanity.io (Netlify) It is working perfectly fine when I'm using localhost. However, when I deploy the site to Netlify, graphql query reverts back to the beginning list. Here is the image of the localhost Graphql

[image]

Then, I can deploy the studio and still everything is fine, but when I push the front end, deployment fails and tells me

[image]

I have done the graphql deploy and tried it again, but the result is the same

I have been trying to solve it last 2 days, but no luck. Maybe you guys can help me with this.

Here is the git link as well. https://github.com/BoraALAP/jasperspaws.git

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, With the git push new deployment, worked fine. If you have theories, I would be happy to hear.

Comment: Hello! I suggest making an edit to the top of your post saying it is resolved.